# Ubuntu 12.04 on Acer C720 - Touchpad problem after HWE update

Tags: touchpad

Couple of days ago, I rebooted my Ubuntu 12.04 and it asked me to update HWE or update to a newer version of the system. I decided to update HWE. Firstly it wasn't succesful because of the lack of the free space on disk, but later I've finished with it.

The problem after that is that touchpad stopped working.

I did:

```
export DISPLAY=:0    
xinput list
```

xinpit list doesn't see the touchpad.

I did:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

And it returned: "Couldn't find synaptic properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"

I did:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse    
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

No result.
**xserver-xorg-input-synaptics** is the newest version. Reinstalling didn't help.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

didn't help as well.

I guess I need to download some driver, but I have no idea about it. Could you please tell me how I can try to fix the problem. I'm new to Linux so sorry for possible gapes in my knowledge.

Just in case:
I use Bodhi Linux 2.4.0 with Enlightment. "uname -a" is:
Linux bodhi32-Peppy 3.13.0-37-generic #64~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 24 21:39:43 UTC 2014 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

As sudo or root

command line

```
 egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices
```

If you have the output somthing like:

```
 N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad"
```

If not , you need to install synaptic-touchpad from package manager

Edit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf

```
 nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

you must have

```
 Section "InputClass"
         Identifier "touchpad catall"
         Driver "synaptics"
         MatchIsTouchpad "on"
         Option "TapButton1" "1"
         Option "VertEdgeScroll" "1"

 End Section
```

add missing line

ctrl + o and enter (to save)

ctrl x

**Reboot**

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of this question. Solved the problem by installing Bodhi Linux RC1 and updating to Ubuntu 14.04. Other ways didn't work

Special c720 iso image with the latest release of Bodhi Linux (I've installed now this one) can be found in the blog of Jeff Hoogland: http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.ru/2014/06/bodhi-linux-300-release-candidate-1.html